# CanActivate guard leads to multiple http calls

Tags: angular, canactivate

I observed strange behavior with my CanActivate guard (Angular 10.2.5):

```
export class VersionGuardService implements CanActivate {

  constructor(private router: Router, private http: HttpClient){
  }

  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> {
    console.log("In the Guard");
    return this.http.request<any>('get',`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users`).pipe(
       tap(resp => console.log("Response: ", resp)),
       map(resp => false)
    );

    //return of(false);
  }
}
```

Routes in app-routing.module.ts looks like this:

```
const routes: Routes = [    
    {
      path: 'login',
      component: LoginComponent,
      canActivate: [VersionGuardService]
    },
    {
      path: 'logout',
      component: LogoutComponent
    },
    {
      path: 'error',
      component: ErrorComponent
    },
    {
      path: '',
      redirectTo: 'login',
      pathMatch: 'full'
    }
];
```

If i invoke app with above code i got `Too many calls to Location or History APIs within a short timeframe` error (in Firefox). When I inspect console output in the browser - indeed there is a lot of (nearly 200) entries with `In the Guard` message. If I inspect the network tab in dev tools i see a lot of invokation of GET on remote service `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users` with `NS_BINDING_ABORTED` message in the "Transferred" column in network dev tools tab.

**Edit 1** The stream from http call does not provides any data (No entry beginning with "Response: " in console log. So it is not issue with how pipe after http call is constructed.

**The question is why is this happening?** What causes the canActivate method execute more than one time?

For example if I remove http call and leave it like this:

```
@Injectable()
export class VersionGuardService implements CanActivate {

  constructor(private router: Router, private http: HttpClient){
  }

  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> {
    console.log("In the Guard");
    return of(false);
  }
}
```

It works as expected (only one entry 'In the Guard` in the Firefox console).

The reason why I want to use Guard is to check app version compatibility (with backend services) on website initialization and decide whatever load login window or redirect to error message site.

**Edit 2**
If I move guard into "later" link in Routes (i mean: the link which is executed later in the app) and guard works as expected. So I though it an is issue with app initialization, so I prepared stackblitz with guard on first link:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-qgfdk3
And it also works as expected.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Please try by adding take(n)  operator  and  catchError(() => of(false)) block in  http request

Comment: Unfortunatelly this is not the case, stream does not provides any data, i provided additional description to mark that

Answer (score 1):

After few hours of code inspection it appeared, that there was an HTTP Interceptor defined somewhere else in the code. The tricky part was, that Http interceptor redirected to '/login' if there was no auth token. So, after I added CanActivate guard with http call (where no auth header is required) on '/login' route - the disaster was ready: User -> /login -> CanActivate -> http call -> /login (because no auth header) -> CanActivate -> http call -> /login and so on in a loop to the browser `Too many calls to Location or History APIs within a short timeframe` After making HTTP Interceptor work conditionally solution started to work as expected.

Comment: Can you give some example how you did it?